# Question regarding Energy Conservation

Tags: classical-mechanics

> A point mass $m$ is projected from the earth surface with speed $v_0$ and at an angle $θ$ above the horizontal. Assume that the gravitational acceleration is constant and has the absolute value $g$.
>
> Use energy conservation to show that, at any time, the velocity of the particle is
> equal in magnitude to the magnitude of the velocity it would acquire in falling freely
> to that point from a height $\dfrac{v_0^2}{2g}$ above the earth surface.

I have worked out that the kinetic energy $T$ of the projected particle is $$T=\frac{1}{2}m(v_0^2-2v_0gt\sin\theta+g^2t^2)$$

And the potential energy $V$ of the projected particle is $$V(t)=mgtv_0\sin\theta-\frac{1}{2}mg^2t^2$$

Now the initial energy of the falling particle is $$E_0=\frac{v_0^2}{2}m$$

How would I work out the final energy of the particle and then complete the answer to the question?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We note that for our projected particle we have acceleration vector:

$$\vec{a}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -g\end{pmatrix}$$

And thus we have velocity vector:

$$\vec{v}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\cos(\theta) \\ v_{0}\sin(\theta) - gt\end{pmatrix}$$

Integrating again and setting $\vec{s}(0)=\vec{0}$, we get:

$$\vec{s}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}v_{0}\cos(\theta)\:t \\ v_{0}\sin(\theta)\:t-\frac{g}{2}t^{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

We note that:

$$T(t)=\frac{1}{2}m\|\vec{v}(t)\|^{2}=\frac{1}{2}m\left(v_{0}^{2}\cos^{2}(\theta)+v_{0}^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)-2gtv_{0}\sin(\theta)+g^{2}t^{2}\right) \\ =\frac{1}{2}m\left(v_{0}^{2}+g^{2}t^{2}-2gtv_{0}\sin(\theta)\right)$$

And $$V(t)=mgh=mgs_{y}(t)=mg\left(v_{0}\sin(\theta)t-\frac{g}{2}t^{2}\right)$$

Summing the kinetic and potential energy:

$$E(t)=T(t)+V(t)=\frac{1}{2}m\left(v_{0}^{2}+g^{2}t^{2}-2gtv_{0}\sin(\theta)\right)+mg\left(v_{0}\sin(\theta)t-\frac{g}{2}t^{2}\right) \\=\frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}+\frac{mg^{2}t^{2}}{2}-\frac{mg^{2}t^{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}$$

As required.

Comment: Just a note: I didn't initially read, but your question says to use conservation of energy, I assumed otherwise, this means we can trivially see that at $t=0$, $V(t)=0$, $T(t)=\frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^{2}$ and therefore it must hold at all times.